# Multiple Linear regression using modules in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, module, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to use R Shiny Modules to do a linear regression.  The idea is as follows:

1. I have a module which takes a data.table  as an input to the function.
2. The module UI then asks for the X and Y variables for the linear regression
3. and upon click of a button should perform the linear regression and print the summary output.

I tried the below code, but is throwing up an error which I am unable to fix.

Kindly help.

**Code**

```
Linear.Regression.UI <- function(id, data.tibble){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("ClickforRegression"), label = "Click Here to Do Regression"),
    
    selectInput(inputId = ns("Regression.Y.Input"),
                label = "Select Regression Dependent Variable",
                choices = names(data.tibble),
                ),
    selectInput(inputId = ns("Regression.X.Input"),
                label = "Select Regression Independent Variables",
                choices= names(data.tibble),
                multiple=TRUE),
    
    verbatimTextOutput("Linear.Model.Output.Summary")
  )#end of tagList

}#end of Linear.Regression.UI


Linear.Regression.Server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    observeEvent(eventExpr = input$ClickforRegression,
                 linear.model <-  lm(reformulate(input$Regression.X.Input, input$Regression.Y.Input), data = data.tibble)
                 )#end of observeEvent
    
    
    output$Linear.Model.Output.Summary <- renderPrint(summary(linear.model()))
    
    
  })#end of moduleServer
  
}


Regression.App <- function(data.tibble){
  ui <- fluidPage(
    Linear.Regression.UI("Data", data.tibble = iris)
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session)
  {
    Linear.Regression.Server("Data")
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}


Regression.App()
```

**Error**

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3883
Warning: Error in is.data.frame: object 'data.tibble' not found
  [No stack trace available]
```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: Apologies. I edited my original post with the error

Comment: You ned to pass `data.tibble` to the `Linear.Regression.Server` function, not the UI.  You can populate the dropdown lists for the `selectInput`s in the UI using `updateSelectInput` from within a reactive context inside `Linear.Regression.Server`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code also needed a `ns` fix but the main fix was passing the data to the server:

```r
Linear.Regression.UI <- function(id, data.tibble){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("ClickforRegression"), label = "Click Here to Do Regression"),
    
    selectInput(inputId = ns("Regression.Y.Input"),
                label = "Select Regression Dependent Variable",
                choices = names(data.tibble),
    ),
    selectInput(inputId = ns("Regression.X.Input"),
                label = "Select Regression Independent Variables",
                choices= names(data.tibble),
                multiple=TRUE),
    
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("Linear.Model.Output.Summary"))
  )#end of tagList
  
}#end of Linear.Regression.UI


Linear.Regression.Server <- function(id, data.tibble ){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    linear.model<- reactiveVal()
    observeEvent(eventExpr = input$ClickforRegression,{ message("sdf");
      linear.model(lm(reformulate(input$Regression.X.Input, input$Regression.Y.Input), data = data.tibble))}
    )#end of observeEvent
    
    
    output$Linear.Model.Output.Summary <- renderPrint(summary(linear.model()))
    
    
  })#end of moduleServer
  
}


Regression.App <- function(data.tibble){
  ui <- fluidPage(
    Linear.Regression.UI("Data", data.tibble = iris)
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session)
  {
    Linear.Regression.Server("Data", data.tibble = iris)
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}


Regression.App()
```

Comment: Thanks very much  @Bart.  I have two follow up questions please. 1) linear.model is already in the observeEvent Handler.  Yet, you define linear.model <- reactiveVal() . Why is this necessary.  2) Why doesn't the assignment operator for ``` linear.model <- lm(reformulate(input$Regression.X.Input, input$Regression.Y.Input), data = data.tibble)``` work?  Why should we put that in brackets -- this is the first time i am encountering this actually.

Comment: I think assigning a value withing `observeEvent` does not produce a reactive value. Thats why I figured out this way would work. I'm sure other options exist by it is important that `linear.model` becomes a reactive that you can use later.